# How to retrieve HTML table data in PHP?

Tags: php, html-table

I'm creating a dynamic table where a user can add records(rows) and enter data. Table cells consists listboxes, text input, file input fields. When a user submits this data I'm getting only the last record(row) data through POST variable in PHP file. Even I tried to get the data using a hidden variable but no use. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the names of your inputs are unique. In your situation where you have more than one set of inputs that are the same I would use HTML arrays.

```
<input name="my_input[]" />
```

The [PHP manual has a set of examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) where this technique is put into action.